# Is it possible to override js scripts?

Tags: javascript, overrides, virtuemart, template-override, module-display

I'm using a layout override to modify the cart module for Virtuemart, but the ajax request deletes part of my code when it updates. Because of this, I would like to change not only the template, but also the javascript routine the module calls.

I could get the behavior I want quickly by altering the module itself, but I was wondering if I could clone the code (which is inside a js file, it is not a part of default.php) and place it inside the override, so that I don't have to fix it every time I update Virtuemart.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no...

Let's start with the "no" - The Joomla core devs have created a way to inject scripts, but no (API) way to remove them.

And, "Yes" , but it's complicated....

You'll need to create a Joomla system plugin to affect the removal.

If you do it any sooner than onBeforeCompileHead - you might end up with another script injecting it again.

This example just removes a script - because I'm injecting a new one elsewhere.  You could modify this to remove and replace at the same time - but that's up to you to decide.

This is how I did it for a BS3 template I wrote.  I really needed to ditch the BS 2.3 javascript and replace it with BS3 javascript.  The plugin was written to accommodate removing multiple javascripts, although this example only shows one.

```
class PlgSystemRWBS3 extends JPlugin {

function onBeforeCompileHead() {
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $cfg = JFactory::getConfig();
    $min = $cfg->get('debug', 0, 'INTEGER') ? '' : '.min';
    $remove = array(
        '/media/jui/js/bootstrap'.$min.'.js'
    );
    $this->_removeScript($doc, $remove);
}

private function _removeScript($o, $remove) {
    $removed = false;
    foreach($remove as $r) {
        $found = preg_grep('/'.preg_quote($r,'/').'$/', array_keys($o->_scripts));
            if(count($found) > 0) {
                unset($o->_scripts[array_shift($found)]);
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Food for thought: https://3v4l.org/sgnYF

Comment: @mickmackusa - looks nice, but fails if you're trying to remove a specific script using its path.  For example, if an extension is loading its own version of jquery and you prefer the built-in version - so you specify it with full path.  Using your method, all files matching jquery.js would get removed.

Comment: Right, so using full paths makes it more reliable. https://3v4l.org/QEJ09  Oh, I see, you are not necessarily using full paths -- you are using longer paths that [end with](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php). https://3v4l.org/0QXaZ

Comment: @mickmackusa As far as Joomla is concerned, it's a full path from the web root, as JPATH::root(true) will be prepended to each item when the head is generated.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the author of your component will provide a way to do such an override, so check the documentation first. If that is not possible, brute force works:

I recently solved this problem for myself by inserting a rule at the top of my .htaccess file on the server. Most Apache servers will handle this correctly. The rule would look like this:

```
Redirect 301 /components/path/to/your/script/thescript.js https://yourdomain.com/templates/your_template/html/js/thescript.js
```

The caveat is you need to remember that this exists. It will override any future updates to this script which the developer provides.